# CSS: how to float two divs horizontally on the same line with consistent margin?

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/enRkR/1229/)

HTML:

```
 <div class="leftwrapper">
  <div class="left">left div</div>
  <div class="middle">middle div</div>
 </div>
 <div class="right">right div</div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftwrapper{
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
}

.left{
    float:left;
    background:green;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 75px;
}

.middle{
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.right{
    float: right;
    background:red;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 75px;
}
```

In the above example, I would like to:

1. Keep all three divs on the same line when resizing the browser (currently, the right div moves beneath the left),
2. Make it so the blue/middle div resizes to fill the space between left and right.  As it stands, when you expand the browser the margin grows.  How do you keep it consistent?

As a note: the structure of the HTML divs is intentional ('leftwrapper' containing two divs, floating alongside the right div), so please no answers involving restructuring of the divs!

Comment: max width 75px is that correct?

Comment: used 75px as an example in JSFiddle - can be anything, as long as it is constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a `flex parent`, and use `flex-grow` to make the elements grow to fill the available space where you want that to happen.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.grow {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.middle {
  background: blue;
}

.left {
  background: green;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 75px;
}

.right {
  background: red;
  width: 30%;
  max-width: 75px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="leftwrapper flex grow">
    <div class="left">left div</div>
    <div class="middle grow">middle div</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">right div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The other answers provided (using calc(100% - 75px) to adjust the width still leave one issue:  when browser window is condensed, the margin between middle and right divs grows.  Your answer fixes that issue!  Many thanks

Comment: @j.winslow no sweat! flex is awesome.

Comment: @j.winslow be sure to select the best answer as the accepted solution once the issue is resolved (the checkmark by the answers)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to this and it'll work nicely.

```css
.leftwrapper {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 75px);
}

.middle {
  background: blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.left {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 75px;
}

.right {
    float: left;
    background: red;
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 75px;
}
```

What I've done is change the width of `.leftwrapper` to 100% but added in a `max-width` property and used `calc()` to ensure it's also `75px` smaller than 100% of the space it can fill up. That way resizing the viewport ensures it stays on one line nicely.

***MDN information about [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc).***

Comment: Many thanks for this - solves my issues and dropped some knowledge on me at the same time.  Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome, `calc()` is great for things like this and has good support so far.

Answer (score 0):

@j.winslow I just updated the JSFIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/enRkR/1232/

I add this:

```
.leftwrapper{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: calc(100% - 75px);
}
```

This is what you're looking for? Regards!